# Google Earth Engine Reducing Landsat Global Inland Waters Raster to Vector

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, vectorization

I'm trying to create a vector outline of the water areas of the Landsat Global Inland Water raster in Earth Engine. I get the error "Line 3: water.addBands is not a function" from the following code:

```
var water = ee.ImageCollection("GLCF/GLS_WATER");

var vectors = water.addBands(water).reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'regions'
});
```

Comment: `addBands()` is a function for an ee.Image object, but not for an ee.ImageCollection. You're working with an ee.ImageCollection, so you won't be able to do that without mapping the function to the collection (although I don't really understand why you want to add a duplicate band to your existing dataset).

Comment: I was having trouble getting reduceToVectors to work (error: `water.reduceToVectors({ same as above }) is not a function`) and was trying different approaches, addBands probably isn't the best way to go about it. Do you know why `water.reduceToVectors` alone was not working?

Comment: Do you try to get the water areas globally (in small scale)? If so, it is not recommended. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#dont-use-a-ridiculously-small-scale-with-reducetovectors